# Wikidata SPARQL: how to include labels for grouped-by attributes

Tags: localization, sparql, aggregation, wikidata

I have a query that works OK:

```sql
SELECT ?language (COUNT (?lexeme) as ?lexemeCount) {
  ?lexeme dct:language ?language .
}
GROUP BY ?language
```

However, I can't think of how to add labels for languages (instead, or alongside with) language entity URIs.  This fails with a time out exception on Wikidata:

```sql
SELECT ?languageLabel (COUNT (?lexeme) as ?lexemeCount) {
  ?lexeme dct:language ?language .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
  }
}
GROUP BY ?languageLabel
```

So does this:

```sql
SELECT ?languageLabel (COUNT (?lexeme) as ?lexemeCount) {
  ?lexeme dct:language ?language .
  ?language rdfs:label ?languageLabel .
  FILTER(lang(?languageLabel) = 'en') .
}
GROUP BY ?languageLabel
```

What query's result would include language *name*s, rather than URIs?

Comment: `select ?languageLabel ?lexemeCount
{
  {
  SELECT ?language (COUNT (?lexeme) as ?lexemeCount) {
  ?lexeme dct:language ?language .
}
GROUP BY ?language
        }

SERVICE wikibase:label { 
  bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
  }
}`

Comment: can you make it an answer? I would totally accept this!

Comment: if it really works as you were hoping, feel free to post it as an answer and just accept your own answer. Cheers

Comment: Also note that in some cases you should use `langMatches` rather than `lang(...) = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631525/wikidata-sparql-how-to-include-labels-for-grouped-by-attributes#comment112521598_63631525) into a community wiki answer:

```sql
SELECT ?languageLabel ?lexemeCount {   
  {   
    SELECT ?language (COUNT (?lexeme) AS ?lexemeCount) {
      ?lexeme dct:language ?language
    }
    GROUP BY ?language
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"
  }
}
```